FirebaseAdmin.Messagging send notification to all devices without tokens
This is my C# Code
var message = new Message()
{
    Notification = new Notification
    {
        Title = "my title",
        Body = "my body",
    },
    Data = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        ["myData"] = "2837"
    },
    Token = "MY-TOKEN" // there is a mode to send all without token? 
};

var messaging = FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance;
var result = await messaging.SendAsync(message);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
{
    // Message was sent successfully
    return true;
}
else
{
    // There was an error sending the message
    //throw new Exception("Error sending the message.");
    return false;
}

So i need to send to all devices, without insert the token.
There is a way to send to all devices without token?
Or there is a way to add multiple tokens?

There is no "send to all devices" API. The closest equivalent is to have all devices subscribe to a single topic, and then sending a message to that topic. --- To send to multiple tokens, see the SendAll and SendEach methods in the API.
